# Chebotarev's density theorem and density of Frobenius elements

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

Why does the Chebotarev density theorem imply that if $K$ is a number field with only a finite set of primes that ramify in an algebraic closure, then the Frobenius elements corresponding to the unramified primes are dense in $G_K$ (the absolute Galois group)?

Comment: What is your statement of the Chebotarev density theorem? For many people, this *is* the Chebotarev theorem.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "only a finite set of primes that ramify in an algebraic closure"?

Comment: Sorry, the statement is: let $L|K$ a finite Galois extension of number fields, $\sigma\in Gal(L|K)$, $[\sigma]$ its conjugacy class. Then the set of primes $\{\mathfrak{P}:Frob_{\mathfrak{P}}=[\sigma]\}$ has Dirichlet density equal to $|[\sigma]|/|Gal(L|K)|$

Comment: For your last question I mean we require that at most finitely many primes of $K$ may ramifie extended to $\mathcal{O}_\bar{K}$

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand. If $K$ is any number field, then infinitely many primes will ramify in $\overline K$.

Comment: Ok so let K_S the maximal extension of K unramified at the finite set S. I have to prove that the frobenius elements relative of the prime not in S is dense in Gal(K_S/K)

Comment: Sorry - I haven't got round to writing an answer. But a reference is Serre, Abelian l-adic representations and elliptic curves. There's a section (1.2.2) about the chebotarev density theorem.

Comment: See theorem 3.5 in [B. Conrad's lecture notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/676Page/handouts/dirdensity.pdf).